# Matlab delete all documents from MongoDB collection via Java driver

Tags: java, matlab, mongodb

I'm in the process of writing a cleanup routine for a mongodb collection for a unit test via the java driver (i tried the "native" matlab driver but the documentation is, well, scarce).

I can get a connection going (at least i think i can), but i'm stuck at invoking the remove method on a DBCollection object.

I'm running the following code:

```
javaaddpath(pathToJarFile)

import com.mongodb.*;

mongoClient = MongoClient(mHost);
mongoConn = mongoClient.getDB(dbName);
auth = mongoConn.authenticate(user,password);

events = mongoConn.getCollection('events');

events.remove();
```

On the last line i get the error

> No method 'remove' with matching signature found for class 'com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl'.

Since i know that the ´remove´ method exists for the DBCollection class, i'm a bit at a loss currently.

Any help would be appreciated. Note that i'm essentially illiterate when it comes to OOP :-S

---

**Edit:**

Please note that i also tried

```
events.remove({});
```

which results in the same error message.

Comment: _What_ shall be removed from the collection "events"?

Comment: All documents contained within events, hence using the method `remove` without an input argument as per the MongoDB documentation for `remove`.

Comment: Which documentation do you refer to? I can only see `remove` methods on `DBCollection` that take at least one argument.

Comment: Maybe you are referring to [Remove All Documents from a Collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/#remove-all-documents-from-a-collection). According to that you should execute `events.remove({})`. If so, I will update my comment to an answer.

Comment: This could be the culprit. But i just tried to get a cursor with all documents with `find()`, which should indeed be able to be called without a query, then passed that cursor to `remove` and it resulted in the same error. Can `remove` not handle a cursor?

Comment: Regarding your second comment, i tried `({})` as well and it makes no difference. I should have mentioned that. I have edited my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `{}` isn't passed correctly by MATLAB, so creating an empty document and passing it to `remove` does indeed work.

The working code looks like this:

```
javaaddpath(pathToJarFile)

import com.mongodb.*;

mongoClient = MongoClient(mHost);
mongoConn = mongoClient.getDB(dbName);
auth = mongoConn.authenticate(user,password);

events = mongoConn.getCollection('events');

empty = BasicDBObject();
events.remove(empty);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [API documentation of `DBCollection.remove`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.12/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#remove%28com.mongodb.DBObject%29), you must provide a `DBObject` that simply specifies the deletion criteria. It further says to pass an empty document to delete all documents in the collection. At least you must provide an argument.

According to the documentation on how to [remove all documents from a collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/#remove-all-documents-from-a-collection), you simply pass the argument `{}` indicating an empty document to that method. So you must call

```
events.remove( {} );
```

To answer your question in the comments: The argument must be a `DBObject` that describes the remove criteria. A *cursor* is not such a document.

Comment: Unfortunately, `events.remove( {} );` doesn't work either. My only guess right now is that because i'm importing the java driver into Matlab and `{}` in Matlab is an empty cell array, the argument isn't passed to the driver as it should be. I will try creating an empty document object and passing it to `remove`, maybe that will help.

Comment: Then I'm sorry. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, your comment about the type of input argument to `remove` put me on the right way!

Comment: You're welcome. Even if I did not know the correct answer, I'm glad to see that I could put you onto the right path.